# How do residents of Vologda pronounce the name of their city?

Tags: произношение

As far as I know, Russian people in the city of Vologda speak with an accent, in which the unstressed Russian 'о' in some words sounds like a stressed one. I wonder if it's also true for the name of their city. Is the way they pronounce the name of their city - 'Вологда' - different from how all the rest of Russians pronounce it?

Comment: Modern dialect is somewhat different from the classic one, or, more precisely, it is not truly described with those stereotypical features.

Comment: apparently it isn't easy to locate a live example or even a description of local pronunciation of this particular word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally haven't heard how they pronounce it but since a feature of [Vologda group of dialects](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B) is [full оканье (as apposed to partial оканье)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) they're expected to pronounce it as **ВолОгда** (as opposed to standard **Волагда**).

UPD: finally found a recording of the pronunciation, which sounds exactly as i described (not that it was a big mystery to me anyway) with `л` sounding as per *Nikolay Ershov*'s description, with the only caveat that it's a recording of a villager and not of a city resident

> [***Вот помнишь, к нам приезжали, ко мне, девки-ти, из
>   Вологды-то?***](https://youtu.be/qqPL8e5AcCE?t=3s)

Comment: let's wait for someone who've heard how they pronounce or. even more, for someone who is from Vologda )

Comment: @shabunc Their speech is somewhat different from that of Moscovites, but not in stereotypical way, for the distinction has developed very recently, in a few years, and it wasn't quite apparent during the Soviet era. One may probably notice a different tonality and temporal characteristics.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a time stamp of that phrase from the video?

Comment: To me it sounds as if she were saying "из Волёгды-то". :)

Comment: @brilliant hi, the link address contains the time stamp, it's 3 seconds into the video, this sounds like `Ё` because of the retroflex `Л` which is always palatalized, orthographically it may be expressed as `ВолЬОгды`

Answer (score 4):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHJpdQl-v-U) suggests that aside from the full Os, "classic" Vologda accent also realises hard `л` as a retroflex `[ɭ]` as opposed to standard Russian "dark" `[ɫ]`. So ['voɭogdə], vs. standard ['voɫəgdə].

However, not a lot of people generally speak with Northern Russian accents these days, and that video was specifically heritage-themed. Here's a [vox pop on Vologda streets](https://youtu.be/Aa6mFQiniYI) and everybody speaks Central Russian — akanye, `[ɫ]` and all.

Comment: а есть интервью на повседневные темы с этим акцентом, а не искусственная фольклорная сказка?